# Tab click does not work when it has a context menu on hover attached to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have attached a context menu on hover on a bootstrap tab using jquery context menu plugin, the context menu opens fine on hover but the tab click does not work after that. To debug, I attached a mouse click event using global event listener in the chrome developer tools but it couldn't catch any click event either as if no click event occurred.

[image: tab image]

[image: Image of chrome developer tools mouse click event listener]

Here is my Code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<script>
  $(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
      selector: '#one-tab',
      trigger: 'hover',
      callback: function(key, options) {

        console.log(key)
      },
      items: {
        "edit": {
          name: "Edit",
          icon: "edit"
        },
        "cut": {
          name: "Cut",
          icon: "cut"
        },
        copy: {
          name: "Copy",
          icon: "copy"
        },
        "paste": {
          name: "Paste",
          icon: "paste"
        },
        "delete": {
          name: "Delete",
          icon: "delete"
        },
        "sep1": "---------",
        "quit": {
          name: "Quit",
          icon: function() {
            return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="card mt-3 tab-card">
        <div class="card-header tab-card-header">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="one-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#one" role="tab" aria-controls="One" aria-selected="true">One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="two-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#two" role="tab" aria-controls="Two" aria-selected="false">Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="three-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#three" role="tab" aria-controls="Three" aria-selected="false">Three</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active p-3" id="one" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="one-tab">
            <h5 class="card-title">Tab Card One</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade p-3" id="two" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="two-tab">
            <h5 class="card-title">Tab Card Two</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade p-3" id="three" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="three-tab">
            <h5 class="card-title">Tab Card Three</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Link : 
https://jsfiddle.net/uno1yj4r/1/

Comment: Use `!` before `[image][1]` so it render the image in the question. Or button to upload image that will create this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because context menu builds a click-catcher overlay beneath itself (`#context-menu-layer`) so it can close when you click outside of the menu.

So, what happens there is:

- the click is consumed by the click-catcher, which closes the menu
- a new context menu is then created because you're still hovering the target which opens a context menu on `:hover`.

To get around this, you need to solve two problems:

**a)** you have to be able to click through the click-catcher:

```
#context-menu-layer {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**b)** you have to close the context menu yourself on click

```
 $(window).on('click', () => $('.context-menu-list').trigger('contextmenu:hide'));
```

See it [working](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/56s0rc9t/).

Side note: you shouldn't be using Bootstrap `v4.0.0`. You should use the [latest available version](https://getbootstrap.com/) (Get started button), as it contains a lot of bugfixes and improvements over `v4.0.0`.